# Calling JavaScript function into a P tag

Tags: javascript

I would like to call the following javaScript function so it gets outputted to a HTML P tag, but am not sure how to do this without explicitly calling the function in the HTML file.

I do not want to do this...

```
<p class="showcode">
<script type="text/javascript">
    wise_words();
</script>
</p>
```

I would like to keep the javaScript code all in one js file.

I have tried it this way but this does not seem to work...

```
document.getElementById("showcode").innerHTML = wise_words();
```

I would really appreciate any help as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qfLdE I would like to have the generated text get outputted inside the grey box.

Comment: what your function should do?

Comment: Put the definition of the function in the header, not in the p-tag, and do something like [`$("p").text(wise_words());`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: arnold.NET.JS it should output some text, you can see at the codepen link

Comment: @blgt when you suggest to use a library like jQuery that is not mentioned in the question you should at least tell which library it is. And `wise_words()` is a function call and not a definition.

Comment: @Adam you don't return anything from `wise_words` so why do you expect that something else then `undefined` should be shown?

Comment: @t.niese I did (as you'll see if you click the link). And, the definition is not included in the question. Duh.

Comment: @t.niese you are right, javaScript is not my strong point, I am just trying to get this script working instead of using the script tag in the HTML doc to call the function, and not sure how to

Comment: @Adam the definition in codepen has no `return` statement in `wise_words`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the function in an `onload` handler, so that it is executed after the DOM has been constructed:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("showcode").innerHTML = wise_words();        
}
```

Another problem is that your `wise_words()` function is using `document.write` (please don't use `document.write`) instead of returning a value. You need to return a value:

```
var retText = wiseText[nextVal][0];

nextVal += 1;
writeCookie("wisewords", nextVal.toString(), 33);

return retText;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. If you try it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qfLdE you will see it loads the quotes on a new page

Comment: @Adam Yes, I see that now. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @JLRishe this will not work as their is no "ID" specified by OP he uses the class. so it must be getElementByClassName right?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE OPs code posted in codepen does have an ID for the `p` element: `<p id="showcode"></p>`.

Comment: @JLRishe that doesn't seem to work either, please see here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pufbg

Comment: @Adam You have a stray parenthesis in your updated code: `var reText = (wiseText[nextVal][0];`. If you remove that, it will work.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: Best use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`, as it is better supported (The latter is _not_ supported by IE8, for example, which does support `querySelectorAll`)

Answer (score 1):

Try following using Jquery:

```
$(".showcode").html(wise_words());
```

**NOTE:** Assuming your function returns the HTML/text.

Comment: And why should that work if `document.getElementById("showcode").innerHTML = wise_words();` does not? And you should mention that `$` is jQuery, as this library is not used by the OP. `Assuming your function returns the HTML/text.` well that is actually the problem as the `wise_words` does not return anything.

Comment: This question was _not_ tagged jquery. Don't assume a lib is being used without good reason

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="showcode">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(wise_words());
    </script>
</p>
```

or:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('showcode').innerHTML = wise_words()">
    <p id="showcode">
    </p>
</body>
```

(note `id` instead of `class`).

Comment: OP has stated that he wants to put his code in a `.js` file.